# Sagging uPVC window fixings advice

Tags: windows, window-frame

We've recently had some uPVC windows installed (Luxembourg, Western Europe, btw).

Already after only a month, the larger (wider) windows are sagging slightly (laterally) and don't open/close smoothly.

My builder (who didn't install the windows) says the windows haven't been installed correctly. He pointed out that the windows are quite wide (2470 mm total, 1235mm each pane) and therefore heavy for the hinges (when opened laterally), and that the frames have been fixed in place with brackets (3 either side). Normally, he says, brackets are only used for smaller windows. And anyway, the brackets haven't been placed properly (not by hinges). I attach photos.

Going back to the window installer will be a problem. Long story.

My builder has proposed to drive some long screws into the frames near/above each top hinge right into the brickwork, to give a stronger hold. I don't think he's proposing to dismantle the frames at all, but simply go at it with a drill straight through frame (plastic/metal) and into the brickwork.

Is this a good idea?

I've attached some photos

[image: window size]
[image: living window view]
[image: example brackets]
[image: brackets on inside]

Thanks for any advice
James

Comment: If those mounting points are, indeed, pulling away from the wall, then either longer or wider mounting screws would be the option.

Comment: Another problem appears to be the yellow foam insulation around that one window.  Product could differ in Europe, but in the US that color of yellow insulation is high-expanding and pretty hard when cured.  This can push against window frames and bow them.  If the insulation didn't contribute to the problem, it will at least make it harder to pull the window closer to the side of the opening since it is so hard and takes a lot of force to compress.  There is a different, softer foam insulation used for doors and windows.

Comment: Good spot, @JPhi1618. I wouldn't have thought to look at the difference in colors. I haven't used "regular" and "low expansion door/window" close enough together (or frequently enough) to have noticed the color difference.